# How to create two models at once in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am making an API using DRF. Here I have a model called `Blog` and a model that refers to a `Blog` called `Comment`. When I create the Blog, I want to create the comments in the comments field together. Here is the json request and the code.

request

```
{
 comments: [
    {
     ...
    },
    {
     ...
    }
 ]
}
```

serializers.py

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'

class BlogSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_comments = 
        validated_data.pop('comments')
        blog = Blog.objects.create(**validated_data)

        Comment.objects.bulk_create([
            Comment(**validated_comments, blog=blog) 
            for validated_comment in 
                validated_comments
        ])

        return blog
```

models.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    ...

class Comment(models.Model):
    ...
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

How can I solve this code using queryset alone?

error

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `comments` on serializer `BlogSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Blog` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Blog' object has no attribute 'comments'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`bulk_create`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) inside `create()` to create all the comments in one db hit.

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ...
    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_comments = validated_data.pop('comments')
        blog = Blog.objects.create(**validated_data)

        Comment.objects.bulk_create([
            Comment(**c, blog=blog) for c in validated_comments
        ])
        return blog
```

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. When this method is attempted, the following error occurs:

Comment: Ok can you show you are using the serializer? It seems you are passing a blog instance which means you are not creating a blog?

Comment: I shared my full BlogSerializer

Comment: I meant how you are using it? Are you passing the request data without an instance? Are you using this in a viewset?

Comment: I'm using CreateAPIView and I wrote BlogSerializer in serializer_class

Comment: For now maybe try to use the list field you have earlier and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Comment field in your Blog model.

Something like this:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    ...
    comment = models.ForeignKey(
        Comment,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I revised the question a little, can you confirm it?